# question on self adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries and $A^*A=A^2$.
Does it imply $A=A^*.$

Comment: This is necessarily true if $A$ is invertible.  This is also true if $A$ is normal, by the spectral theorem.

Comment: We can rewrite the equality as 
$$
(A^* - A)A = 0
$$
Perhaps this is helpful.

Comment: but $AB=0$  does not imply $A=0$ or $B=0$.

Comment: I know, but it's a start.  Just adding some thoughts here for what to try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If $A$ is normal and satisfies the above equality, then $A$ is Hermitian, by the spectral theorem.

In the case that $A$ is non-normal, we have
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A^*A) > \sum_{j=1}^n |\lambda|^2 \geq 
\left|\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda^2 \right| = \left|\operatorname{trace}(A^2)\right|
$$
So, if $A$ is not normal, it is impossible to have $A^*A = A^2$.

We conclude that if $A^*A = A^2$, then $A$ is Hermitian, as desired.